# How do I filter objects based on a name match?

Tags: powershell

I am returning a lot of data I would like to filter. The names of the property have this information. I am used to filtering based on `| ? {$_.Name -eq 'Value'}`. I would expect to be able to use the hidden `.pscustomobject` to do this more dynamically.

```
$x = [pscustomobject]@{
   atruevalue = 'sometext'
   afalsevalue = 'sometext'
}

$x | ?{$_.psobject.Properties.Name -like '*true*'}
```

I expect this to return:

```
> atruevalue
> ----------  
> sometext
```

However, it simply returns every item in the object.

Could anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: `$x` is a single object.  You would need to find a way to enumerate its keys/values (which is a better case for a `hashtable` instead)

Comment: I [strongly recommend checking out this blog](https://kevinmarquette.github.io/) on the `hashtable` and `pscustomobject` topics.

Comment: `$x.psobject.properties|? name -like '*true*'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Where-object filters Rows of the input, what your example does.

To Filter columns you need Select-Object.

```
$x = [pscustomobject]@{
      atruevalue = 'sometext'
      afalsevalue = 'sometext'
      atruenightmare = 'someothertext'}
```

---

```
> $x|select ($x.psobject.properties|? name -like '*true*').Name

atruevalue atruenightmare
---------- --------------
sometext   someothertext
```

Comment: Thanks - I ended up using this vs the top answer since it outputs the key-value pair correctly.

Answer (score 5):

If you really do want to filter the properties, then moving things around a bit will do it. This would look like:

```
$x.psobject.Properties | ? {$_.Name -like '*true*'}
```

If you just want the values rather than the properties, then add another stage to the pipeline:

```
$x.psobject.Properties | ? {$_.Name -like '*true*'} | % Value
```

Answer (score 2):

[Bruce Payette's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50768616/45375) shows the simplest solution.

As for:

> Could anyone explain this behavior?

`?`, a built-in alias for the [`Where-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?), acts as a *filter*, which means that if the *filter condition* in the form of an evaluated-for-each-input script block (`{ ... }`) evaluates to `$True`, the input object at hand (represented as `$_` inside the script block) is passed through *as-is*.

To put it differently: it is immaterial what specific properties of the input object your script block examines - if the condition evaluates to `$True`, the *whole input object* is passed through.